# Lightning Date properties issues

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I need to perform a simple business task.

I need to alter date property before sending it to server to minimize server response time.

I need to use LEX (Lightning Experience).

I have declared my Date property

```
<aura:attribute name="month" type="Date"/>
```

but I have noticed that it is stored as a string like "2016-09-08T12:01:11.832Z".

I need to process this string (in my case, I need to convert to start of the month) and I would like to save it in the property.

My Lightning application code looks like following

```
<aura:application>
<aura:attribute name="month" type="Date"/>
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.month}" action="{!c.monthChange}"/>
</aura:application>
```

I have intentionally omitted all unrelated code. My javascript controller looks like following

```
({
monthChange: function( component, event, helper ) {
    debugger;
    if ( window.console ) {
        console.log(component.get("v.month"));
    }
    var s = component.get("v.month");
    var date = new Date(s);
    if ( date.getDate() != 1) {
        var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
//Something has gone wrong. rerender threw an error in 'markup://ui:inputDate' [TypeError: value.split is not a function]
//Failing descriptor: {markup://ui:inputDate}.
//Please try again.
        //component.set("v.month", firstDay );    

        //FATAL_ERROR System.TypeException: Invalid date: 8/1/2016
        //component.set("v.month", firstDay.toLocaleDateString());

        // RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]
        //component.set("v.month", firstDay.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
        // 
        // 
        // Recommended usage is var dateFormat = $A.get("$Locale.dateFormat");
        // but the return value "MMM d, yyyy" doesn't correspond to expected format 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        // 
        // Also $A.localizationService.formatDateTime(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'); doesn't take the date from parameter
        // but instead return always current date "2016-09-08"
        // 
        // https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_l10n.htm

        component.set("v.month", date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + '-01' );    


    }

}
})
```

My very first attempt was to save Date value inside of Date property like following:

```
({
monthChange: function( component, event, helper ) {

    var s = component.get("v.month");
    var date = new Date(s);
    var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
    component.set("v.month", firstDay );    

}
})
```

I received this very misleading error:

```
Something has gone wrong. rerender threw an error in 'markup://ui:inputDate' [TypeError: value.split is not a function]
Failing descriptor: {markup://ui:inputDate}.
Please try again.
```

As far as I could guess from this misleading error it says that LEX expect a DATE property value to BE A STRING and it TRIES to SPLIT it.

Ok... let it be. So I tried to change the code to

```
({
monthChange: function( component, event, helper ) {

    var s = component.get("v.month");
    var date = new Date(s);
    if ( date.getDate() != 1) {
        var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
        component.set("v.month", firstDay.toLocaleDateString());
    }
}
})
```

This time I received error in apex controller like

```
FATAL_ERROR System.TypeException: Invalid date: 8/1/2016
```

I think I should add that I have additional lines like those

```
<aura:application controller="LexCont">
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onInit}"/>
<aura:attribute name="projects" type="Project__c[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="project" type="Id"/>
```

in my application and in my javascript controller

```
onInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.getProjects( component );


    var d = new Date(2010, 2, 3);
    alert( $A.localizationService.formatDate(d, 'YYYY-MM-DD') );

    alert( $A.localizationService.formatDate(d, 'yyyy-MM-dd') );

    alert( $A.localizationService.formatDate(d, 'yyyy-mm-dd') );
}
```

and inside of helper

```
getProjects: function( component ) {
    var action = component.get( "c.getProjects" );

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            var projects = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.projects", projects );
            if ( projects.length > 0 ) {
                component.set("v.project", projects[0].Id );                    
            }
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

and inside my Apex Controller

```
public class LEXCont {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static ProjectModel getProjectModel( Id pId, String selectedMonth ){
        return Services.getProjectModel(pId, selectedMonth);
    }
}
```

My next attempt was

```
({
monthChange: function( component, event, helper ) {
var s = component.get("v.month");
var date = new Date(s);
if ( date.getDate() != 1) {
    var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
    component.set("v.month", firstDay.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
}
}
})
```

Method firstDay.toISOString() returns date in the same format it was when I read the value of property if I skip the time part. However, I received this time error

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Since this method returns date in UTC\GMT format, and the date gets shifted by 1 day in the past each time it is being processed.

My next attempt was following. I started googling and searching for standard methods related to date processing in Lightning. I have read [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_l10n.htm)  that recommended usage is

```
var dateFormat = $A.get("$Locale.dateFormat");
$A.localizationService.formatDateTime(date, dateFormat );
```

However, when I tried to use this approach, the first discrepancy I noticed was that $A.get("$Locale.dateFormat") returns different format than was the date formatted when I retrieved it. It returns "MMM d, yyyy", but the date is expected to be in format 'YYYY-MM-DD' as far as I understand.

Also I noticed that $A.localizationService.formatDateTime(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'); returns always the current date, not the date passed in parameters. So this attempt

```
({
monthChange: function( component, event, helper ) {
var s = component.get("v.month");
var date = new Date(s);
if ( date.getDate() != 1) {
    var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
    // Recommended usage is var dateFormat = $A.get("$Locale.dateFormat");
    // but the return value "MMM d, yyyy" doesn't correspond to expected format 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    // 
    // Also $A.localizationService.formatDateTime(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'); doesn't take the date from parameter
    // but instead return always current date "2016-09-08"
    // 
    // https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_l10n.htm

    component.set("v.month", $A.localizationService.formatDateTime(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') );    
}
}
})
```

was not working as expecting, showing always 9/8/2016 in datepicker instead of the start of the month.

So I decided to try to do manual formatting like this

```
({
monthChange: function( component, event, helper ) {
var s = component.get("v.month");
var date = new Date(s);
if ( date.getDate() != 1) {
    var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
    component.set("v.month", date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + '-01' );    
}
}
})
```

and this was my last hope and last resort and it worked, but I have ugly code.

So, my first question is the following.

Can we achieve this business requirement by more elegant code using standard features or recommended by Salesforce?
(also I wonder why Lightning is still so glitchy that nothing works from the documentation examples - but this would sound like rhetoric question)

My second question is the following.

Why behavior of method $A.localizationService.formatDate(new Date(2010, 2, 3), 'YYYY-MM-DD') differs upon the execution context?

When I run this code from JavaScript developer console

```
var d = new Date(2010, 2, 3);
alert( $A.localizationService.formatDate(d, 'YYYY-MM-DD') );
alert( $A.localizationService.formatDate(d, 'yyyy-MM-dd') );
```

I see

```
2010-03-03
2010-03-03
```

but when I put in javascript controller and open the app it says

```
2016-09-08
2016-09-08
```

Why, why the behavior is different???? Does anyone know that? Can anybody explain this behavior?

---

Update. I was suggested to change in apex controller and services class property type from String to Date and use

```
component.set("v.month", firstDay.toLocaleDateString());
```

It seems to be working (no error happen) but selected value on LEX Calendar doesn't correspond to the value selected

[image: selected value on LEX Calendar doesn't correspond to the value selected],

so I ended up using code which gives me desired behavior

[image: gives me desired behavior]

```
component.set("v.selectedMonth", date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-01' );
```

for now, since getMonth() is zero-based function.